# How to use bundler to install activerecord 3-2-stable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, bundler

I want to install a patched version of active record, say 3-2-stable, but not the whole 3-2-stable branch of rails. What should I add to the Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'activerecord', '3.2'
```

This will also install `activerecords` dependencies (activemodel, activesupport, and arel).

Comment: I don't want the activerecord from the trunk, because it doesn't work well with ruby 2.2. I want activerecord from the branch `3-2-stable` of rails. How to install it with bundler?

Comment: Well, according to [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.2.0) rails 3.2 uses activerecord 3.2. I'm not sure if the rails team does something with it which makes the ruby 2.2 interaction work better, and I'm not sure how you would go about finding that out to be honest.

Comment: Actually I do. It's about the syntax like `def foo(bar = bar); end`, which is no longer valid in ruby 2.2 (maybe not even in 2.0), and should be modified as `def foo(bar = bar()); end`. The 3-2-stable branch found all the occurrence of this and patched them.